# How to subclass scipy.stats.norm?

Tags: python, inheritance, scipy

I'd like to subclass `scipy.stats.norm` so that I can have instances of frozen distributions (i.e. with specific means/variances) with additional functionality.
However, I can't get past the first step of constructing an instance.

**Edit**: here is a transcript of an interactive session that demonstrates my problem (there's nothing up my sleeves)

```
In [1]: import scipy.stats

In [2]: class A(scipy.stats.norm):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         super( A, self).__init__()
   ...:         
   ...:         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/Dave/src/python2.7/density_estimation/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.pyc in __init__(self, momtype, a, b, xa, xb, xtol, badvalue, name, longname, shapes, extradoc)
    958 
    959         if longname is None:
--> 960             if name[0] in ['aeiouAEIOU']:
    961                 hstr = "An "
    962             else:

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I can see that `scipy.stats` is doing some sort of weird thing where `norm` is a specific instance of something (sometype?), but it's not a normal class definition, so I don't see how to invoke a constructor for it.

Edit #2: scipy version may be relevant.

```
In [19]: scipy.__version__
Out[19]: '0.9.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy.stats.norm` is not a class. It is an instance of `scipy.stats.norm_gen`. Calling `norm(*args, **kwds)` will return an instance of `rv_frozen` with `norm` and the arguments that you gave it. If you want a new kind of frozen distribution, subclass `rv_frozen` to add your methods and just instantiate it with `norm` and the arguments. Don't worry about subclassing `norm_gen`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you subclass `rv_continuous` instead of `rv_frozen`?

Comment: The import command looks like: `from scipy.stats.distributions import rv_frozen` and the initial call would be something like `super(className,self).__init__(norm,normprop1,normprop1...)`

Answer (score 1):

I tend to believe that the error lies somewhere in what you're not showing. There should be no problem with the class itself. Indeed:

```
class GaussianKernel(scipy.stats.norm):
def __init__(self, mu, sigma):
    super( GaussianKernel, self).__init__(loc=mu, scale=sigma)

G = GaussianKernel(5,.2)
G.mean() # returns 5
G.std() # returns .2
```

However, it is true that when using scipy, one should call:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
```

instead of:

```
import scipy.stats.norm
```

Hope this helps...

EDIT:

The weird behavior you're referring to seems to be that the class 'norm' can also be used as a function. They call that a rv_frozen object in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)

There is a paragraph about subclassing [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html) that might be of some help hopefully. The rv_continuous module cannot be used as a function, maybe that's the right way to go!

Comment: I tried the exact same lines of your edit in ipython and got no error. I'm afraid I'm not qualified to help further but if I were you I'd have a look at the version of scipy (I'm using 0.12.0). Also have a look at my edit. I hope it will work out for you.

Comment: One more thing: try with the superclass scipy.stats.distributions.norm_gen, that might be it!

Comment: subclassing `norm_gen` yields an instance that is like a generic distribution (like `scipy.stats.norm` itself) rather than instances that are like frozen distributions (which is what I want).