# Subclass of Scipy.Stats.exponweib not calling __init__ or other functions

Tags: python, class, scipy

I am attempting to make a subclass to simplify the inputs to the `scipy.stats.exponweib` package as well as add some extra functions.  Simplifed the class is in its own files call `weibull.py`

```
from scipy.stats import exponweib
# import scipy

class weibull(exponweib):

    def __init__(self,beta,nu):
        super(weibull,self).__init__(a=1,c=beta,loc=0,scale=nu)
        print beta
        print nu

    def doSomething(self,s):
        print(s)
```

My test script looks something like:

```
from weibull import weibull

w = weibull(2.6,2600)
print('%0.10f'%w.pdf(1000))
w.doSomething('Something')
```

It seems as though my `__init__` is not running at all, none of the print statements run and an error is thrown on the `doSomething` routine.

The output in the terminal looks like:

```
Codes> python weibull_testHarness.py
0.0000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weibull_testHarness.py", line 5, in <module>
    w.doSomething('Something')
AttributeError: 'rv_frozen' object has no attribute 'doSomething'
```

Comment: I don't think `exponweib` itself is a `class`. Run `import inspect; print(inspect.isclass(exponweib))` to verify for yourself. The class is `rv_continuous` or `exponweib_gen` and `rv_continuous` is imported as `from scipy.stats import rv_continuous`. I think that's what you need to inherit from to be able to make the modifications. Try it and report if it's working.

Comment: `exponweib` you imported is an object. `exponweib_gen` is probably the class you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per NumPy/SciPy developer [Robert Kern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976359/190597), subclass `rv_frozen`, not `exponweib`.

Notice that `exponweib` is an [*instance* of the class `exponweib_gen`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L1241).

```
In [110]: stats.exponweib
Out[110]: <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.exponweib_gen at 0x7fd799db2588>
```

`exponweib` [is itself a callable](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L771) which returns an instance of `rv_frozen`.

```
In [107]: exponweib(a=1, c=2.6)
Out[107]: <scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen at 0x7fd7997282b0>
```

So following this pattern, by analogy, `w = weibull(2.6, 2600)` will be an instance of `rv_frozen`. If you want `w` to have additional methods, then you'll need to subclass `rv_frozen`, not `exponweib`, nor `exponweib_gen`, nor `rv_continuous`.

---

```
import scipy.stats as stats

class my_frozen(stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen):

    def __init__(self, dist, *args, **kwds):
        super(my_frozen,self).__init__(dist, *args, **kwds)
        print(kwds)

    def doSomething(self,s):
        print(s)

def weibull(beta, nu):
    dist = stats.exponweib # an instance of stats._continuous_distns.exponweib_gen
    dist.name = 'weibull'
    return my_frozen(dist, a=1, c=beta, loc=0, scale=nu)

w = weibull(2.6, 2600)
print('%0.10f'%w.pdf(1000))
w.doSomething('Something')
```

yields

```
{'loc': 0, 'scale': 2600, 'c': 2.6, 'a': 1}
0.0001994484
Something
```

Comment: Just curious, why is the original `class weibull(exponweib):` is legal? I think callable is not the only requirement.

Comment: @HaochenWu: `class Foo(Bar)`, [causes Python to call `type(Bar)('Foo', (Bar,), clsdct)`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-November/057906.html) to create the class `Foo`. If you (erroneously) *try* to define a class with `class weibull(exponweib)`, Python calls `type(exponweib)('weibull', (exponweib,), clsdict)`, which returns an instance of `exponweib_gen`. It is "legal" Python --  it assigns `'weibull'` to `momtype` and `'(exponweib,)'` to `a` and `clsdict` to `b`. *At this stage* no error occurs, but it is not returning a sensible class (nor a sensible distribution).